# JQuery datatable not filling from AJAX call despite successful response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

I have a dot net aspx page with a table set up as a JQuery DataTable (https://datatables.net/) using an AJAX call to get the data from a Web Method.  The data is returned as a JSON object.

The mechanics of each part seems to be working correctly.  The Web Method is called and returns a valid JSON object (according to JSONLint) and I can access and handle the returned data in the "success" callback function of the AJAX call.

However, the datatable appears on the page without any body rows, just the header and footer.

**HTML section from .aspx page**

```
<div id="divIssueDetailsTable">
    <table id="tblIssueDetails" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript function to create datatable** (Including test code inside the success callback function to test the JSON object returned)

```
$('#tblIssueDetails').DataTable(
    {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "cache": false,
        "destroy": true,
        "ajax":
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebServices/WSGetData.asmx/ReturnIssues",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "",
                success: function (results) {
                    toastr["success"]("AJAX call succeeded.", "Success:");
                    var objJSON = $.parseJSON(results.d);
                    $(objJSON.data).each(function () {
                        alert(this.Age);
                    });
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    toastr["error"]("There has been a problem retrieving the information from the database. " + e.responseText, "Error:");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#divIssueDetailsTable').show();
                }
            }
    });
```

**What the web method is returning** (test data)

> d: "{ "data":
>   [{"Name":"Freddy","Age":"23"},{"Name":"Jane","Age":"23"},{"Name":"Rod","Age":"23"}]
>   }"

The weird thing is, all of the separate parts seem to be working correctly, but it just not refreshing the table.

I can't find any links on datatables just refusing to display data.  I have tried the following:

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html
[fill datatable with json and web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638987/fill-datatable-with-json-and-web-service)
[Datatables not refreshing after second network request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191697/datatables-not-refreshing-after-second-network-request)
[datatables dataSrc function not called on successful ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478730/datatables-datasrc-function-not-called-on-successful-ajax-response)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you remove .data from $(objJSON.data).each ?  Try just $(objJSON).each

Comment: That's test code to handle the object inside the success function.  If I remove ".data" I'll get "undefned" in the alert box.  The issue is that the datatable is not displaying the returned data.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DataTables docs on `ajax` say:

> `success` - Must *not* be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables. To manipulate / transform the data returned by the server use `ajax.dataSrc` (above), or use `ajax` as a function (below).

By supplying your own `success` callback, you deprive DataTables access to the Ajax result.

You can instead use a the `dataSrc` callback, which takes the server response and must return the object for DataTables to use:

```
dataSrc: function (results) {
    toastr["success"]("AJAX call succeeded.", "Success:");
    var objJSON = $.parseJSON(results.d);
    return objJSON.data;
},
```

Comment: Point taken about not overriding functions - thanks.  Callback functions used for debugging so have removed them and added the dataSrc function as suggested.  Now getting an "Unknown parameter" error from datatables..... which I can now go and investigate.